# Mapbox GL JS Loop / Iterate through clustered geojson features

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I use clustering on a mapbox source with geojson as input (sevaral features) to merge some markers on a symbol layer.

```
const source = {
  type: 'geojson',
  data: {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [...]
  },
  cluster: true,
  clusterRadius: 15
}
...
```

After clustering I need the clusterId of all the clusters within the source. In the data property of the source object I only can find the original feature collection (without clusters)

Anybody knows how I can loop through all the clusters to get clusterIds ? I can not find any property within the source object containing only the clusters.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines should work:

```js
for (const cluster of map.querySourceFeatures({ id: 'mygeojson', filter: ['get', 'cluster'] })) {
  console.log(cluster.properties.cluster_id);
}
```